# How to include a file in vagrant vbox

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

Lets say I'm running an instance of a box. How to include a file that physically resides in the same directory as box and vagrantfile? I suppose I need to state that in the vagrantfile. How should that include look?

My vagrantfile (excluding the comments) is:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant_data"
```

Running the box I get:

```
(...)
default: SSH auth method: private key
default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
```

I can 'vagrant ssh' into it, but theres no /vagrant_data folder available

Answer (score 0):

From [vagrant doc](https://www.vagrantup.com/intro/getting-started/synced_folders.html)

> By default, Vagrant shares your project directory (remember, that is the one with the Vagrantfile) to the `/vagrant` directory in your
>   guest machine.
>
> Note that when you `vagrant ssh` into your machine, you're in `/home/vagrant`. `/home/vagrant` is a different directory from the synced
>   `/vagrant` directory.

so if you have a file that *physically resides in the same directory as vagrantfile* you will be able to access in the VM from the `/vagrant` directory.

Comment: vagrant ssh with ls /vagrant shows no files included. However, when I run vagrant up I'm receiving authentication failure

Comment: _I'm receiving authentication failure_ ? but you can connect ? it might mean the `/vagrant` folder from the box (some box owner do disable) you can add the following line in your Vagrantfile `config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: false` if you want to have the default `/vagrant` folder back or replace `/vagrant` by any other name.

Comment: yes I can run vagrant ssh and connect into the running machine. Still nothing found with ls /vagrant. I also inserted that line you mentioned.

Comment: add `config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant_data"` and restart the VM by running `vagrant reload` files should be in `/vagrant_data` directory

Comment: I did that but there is no directory /vagrant_data created. When trying to perform vagrant reload I get:    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...

Comment: can you edit your initial question with your Vagrantfile and the output of `vagrant up`